Why numpy.array so slow when editing the data inside?
I wrote an algorithm that uses a long list. Since numpy.array should perform better in dealing with long data, I wrote another version using numpy.array.
list version:
import math
def PrimeTable(n:int) -> list[int]:
   nb2m1 = n//2 - 1
   l = [True]*nb2m1
   for i in range(1,(math.isqrt(n)+1)//2):
      if l[i-1]:
         for j in range(i*3,nb2m1,i*2+1):
            l[j] = False
   return [2] + [i for i,v in zip(range(3,n,2), l) if v]

array version:
import math, numpy
def PrimeTable2(n:int) -> list[int]:
   nb2m1 = n//2 - 1
   l = numpy.full(nb2m1, True)
   for i in range(1,(math.isqrt(n)+1)//2):
      if l[i-1]:
         for j in range(i*3,nb2m1,i*2+1):
            l[j] = False
   return [2] + [i for i,v in zip(range(3,n,2), l) if v]

It turns out that numpy.array version is 1x slower than list version. The graph:where y0 is PrimeTable and y1 is PrimeTable2
Why is numpy.array so slow, and how can I improve it?

How much slower is 1x slower?

It takes twice the time to complete the same task.

Numpy is optimized for vectorized operations, where large chunks of data are processed in bulk. Instead of updating element-by-element(l[j] = False) we can use slicing to update a range of values at once. Also reducing the number of python loops should make the code more effective.
I've further optimised the code by using a single boolean array. The sieve tracks only odd numbers directly. This eliminates the need for multiplication and division steps for odd indices during iteration. After the sieve is complete, the prime numbers are directly reconstructed from the indices, avoiding intermediate computations.
Try out this updated code. This should work better than the list version of code:
import numpy as np

def PrimeTable2_optimized_v2(n: int) -> list[int]:
    if n < 2:
        return []
    if n == 2:
        return [2]

    # Only consider odd numbers; even numbers > 2 are not prime
    sieve = np.ones(n // 2, dtype=bool)
    limit = int(n**0.5) + 1

    for i in range(1, limit // 2 + 1):
        if sieve[i]:
            start = 2 * i * (i + 1) 
            sieve[start::2 * i + 1] = False

    # Convert sieve to primes
    primes = 2 * np.nonzero(sieve)[0] + 1 
    primes[0] = 2 
    return primes.tolist()


That’s brilliant! I have further optimized it a bit (updated in my answer).

Why it is slow
numpy.array is designed to vertorize operations, i.e. process a whole array of data at once. Meanwhile, list is designed to store different data and access them one by one.
In the original code, the second for loop change elements one by one, so it is more friendly to list.
How to improve
As mentioned before, vertorization is preferred. Therefore, replace the inner for loop with slicing:
l[i*3:nb2m1:i*2+1] = False

Besides, the list comprehension is essentially a for loop, replace it using np.nonzero(for simplicity, import numpy as np):
return [2] + (2*np.nonzero(l)[0]+3).tolist()

Furthermore, instead of np.full, we should use np.ones whenever we only need one:
l = np.ones(n//2 - 1, dtype=bool)

The optimized version:
def PrimeTable_optimized(n:int) -> list[int]:
   if n <= 2:
      return []
   a = (math.isqrt(n)+1)//2
   l = np.ones(n//2 - 1, dtype=bool)
   for i,j,k in zip(range(a-1), range(3,3*a,3), range(3,2*a+1,2)):
      if l[i]:
         l[j::k] = False
   return [2] + (2*np.nonzero(l)[0]+3).tolist()

To improve further, we don’t need to consider multiples of 3. We would have to separate 5,11,17,… and 7,13,19,…. We can combine these two sequences of numbers into one array. Besides, we can return an np.array instead of list.
Final version:
def PrimeTable_combined_nparray(n:int) -> np.array:
   # handle first few cases
   if n <= 7:
      if n >= 6:
         return np.array((2,3,5))
      elif n >= 4:
         return np.array((2,3))
      elif n == 3:
         return np.array((2,))
      return np.array((),dtype=int)
   
   # no need to consider multiple of 2 and 3
   sieve = np.ones((n + 10)//6 + n//6, dtype=bool)
   for i in range(2,(math.isqrt(n) + 7) // 3, 2):
      if sieve[i]: # even sieve and odd sieve works differently
         sieve[(3 * i - 2) * i + 1::6 * i - 2] = False
         sieve[3 * i * i::6 * i - 2] = False
      if sieve[i+1]:
         sieve[(3 * i + 2) * i + 1::6 * i + 2] = False
         sieve[(3 * i + 6) * i + 2::6 * i + 2] = False
   sieve = np.nonzero(sieve)[0]
   sieve = 3 * sieve - 1 - (sieve & 1)
   # we did not consider 2 and 3
   sieve[0] = 2
   sieve[1] = 3
   return sieve

Comparison
Comparing the original two and the first optimization:
y2 = original_array, y1 = original_list, y0 = optimized

Another graph that uses the same inputs as the OP used:

And compare two optimizations:
y0 = optimized, y1 = combined_nparray

